# Eclipse no longer completing my javadocs with params/return tags

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, javadoc

I started a new project this afternoon and now that I've decided to write some comments, the javadocs are acting weird. I've tried resetting the perspective, but no dice. Any tips to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "acting weird"?

Comment: They've probably slapped on makeup and a wig, and started prancing about on a stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the perspective just changes the layout of that perspective back to the default.

In my experience Eclipse is such a big program that the *quickest* way to fix such things, is to extract a fresh version of Eclipse and switch to that.  Then you have default behaviour.  Then you can import your existing projects and keep working.  If the strange behaviour keeps occurring you can use this approach to look for a pattern and *then* you can begin looking for what triggered it

Answer (score 0):

You could try going into the settings for compiling javadocs. 
I found it in Preferences > Java > Compiler > Javadoc.